# Unit testing a Angular service call using karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am getting following **service undefined** error when i try to unit test a service call return in my app . I spend several hours on this , but i couldn't really isolate where the issue comes from . Appreciate if anyone could help me out with this .

```
Firefox 38.0.0 (Windows 8.1) companyService should return a promise for getCompany function FAILED
        minErr/<@C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
        loadModules/<@C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4138:15
        forEach@C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11
        loadModules@C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4099:5
        createInjector@C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:11
        workFn@C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2409:44
        TypeError: companyService is undefined in C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/test/company/Compa
nyServiceSpec.js (line 15)
        @C:/Users/user1m/Documents/mycompany/WebApiRole/test/company/CompanyServiceSpec.js:15:16
Firefox 38.0.0 (Windows 8.1): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.031 secs / 0.014 secs)
```

My karma.conf.js file

```
 // Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
            'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/ng-file-upload/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-pnotify/src/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-local-storage/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/**/*.js',
            'app/app.js',
            'app/**/*.js',
            'test/**/*Spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


     // web server port
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 44555,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Firefox'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

CompanyServiceSpec.js file

```
'use strict';

describe('companyService', function() {

    var $httpBackend, companyService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mycompany'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _companyService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        companyService = _companyService_;
    }));

    it('should return a promise for getCompany function', function() {
        expect(typeof companyService.getCompany('foobar').then).toBe('function');
    }); 

});
```

CompanyService.js file

```
angular.module('mycompany').factory('companyService',
    function($http, mycompanyApiProvider, $upload) {
        'use strict';

        var _company = null;

        function getCompany(companyId) {
            return $http.get(mycompanyApiProvider.url('companies/' + companyId));
        }
    });
```

app.js file

```
angular.module('mycompany', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.router.util',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'jlareau.pnotify',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angularMoment',
    'frapontillo.bootstrap-switch'
]);

angular.module('mycompany').run(function (mycompanyApiProvider, $state, userService, localStorageService,
    $translate, $rootScope, $window, $timeout) {
    'use strict';

    mycompanyApiProvider.setEndpoint('/api/');
    mycompanyApiProvider.loginUrl = '/home/login';

});
```

mycompanyApiProvider.js file

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mycompany')
    .provider('mycompanyApiProvider', function($httpProvider, $provide) {

        $provide.factory('jsonHeaderInterceptor', function() {
            return {
                'request': function(config) {
                    // config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                    return config;
                }
            };
        });

    });
```

Folder structure

```
Folder structure : 
    |WebApiRole/Karma.Conf.js
    |WebApiRole/app/app.js
    |WebApiRole/app/company/CompanyService.js
    |WebApiRole/app/common/services/mycompanyApiProvider.js
    |WebApiRole/test/company/CompanyServiceSpec.js
```

Comment: Where is your `mycompany` module defined?

Comment: @Phil in the app.js file which i have included now .

Comment: What about `mycompanyApiProvider`? Also, I wouldn't name services / factories *"...Provider"*, it's just confusing

Comment: @Phil . mycompanyApiProvider is just a file where token authorizatrions logic goes which is irrelevant for this unit testing case.  the service file i use for calling getcompany method is in CompanyService.js file

Comment: Because `companyService` has an injector dependency on `mycompanyApiProvider`, it needs to exist in order to test the service, either the real provider or a mocked one.

Answer (score 2):

The `companyService` factory doesn't return anything, so it's treated as having returned `undefined`. The test seems to be testing that it returns an object with a `getCompany` function, so you can change it so it does:

```
angular.module('mycompany').factory('companyService', function($http, mycompanyApiProvider, $upload) {
  'use strict';

  var _company = null;

  function getCompany(companyId) {
    return $http.get(mycompanyApiProvider.url('companies/' + companyId));
  }

  return {
    getCompany: getCompany
  };
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response . I still get the error even with the `return {
getCompany: getCompany};` . However i was able to isolate the issue by debugging and it occurs because the execution doesn't enter inside `beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$httpBackend_,_companyService_) {` block . Is it because i am missing some dependecies ?